# onKeyUp not working? maybe it's bad ajax code?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, onkeyup

I am just learning AJAX, and the following HTML file is not working. Every time I release a key, firebug says "login is not a function". I can't figure out why this is. Any help is appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ajax</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeAjax() {
    var ajax;
    try{
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e) {
        try {
            ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert("Your browser is either OLD or BAD! UPDATE!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("btag").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
}
function login() {
    ajax.open("GET", "ajax.php", true);
    ajax.send(null); 
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="makeAjax();">
<form name="login">
Username: <input type="text" onKeyUp="login();" />
<br /><br />
Password: <input type="password" onKeyUp="login();" />
<b id="btag"></b>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onKeyUp="login();"` seems to be finding your form (also named `login`). Renaming the form to something different (e.g. `login_form`) works for me.

Comment: that solved one problem... but now firebug says "ajax is not defined" thanks for your help so far

Comment: ps putting in an alert or a log to the console in the login function would have shown you that it wasn't being called, and that it wasn't the ajax causing this problem

Comment: you would need to define `ajax` globally to be able to access it in the `login` function

Comment: @Ben7005: the 'ajax is not defined' error is because you've declared ajax as block scope inside makeAjax(). The callback function is executed in the window object scope and can't 'see' your ajax variable. Move 'var ajax'; outside of makeAjax();

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different form name.   You have a form named 'login' and a Javascript function called Login.  I think firebug is confused between the two...

Also, put the Ajax variable outside the function, .i.e.

```
var ajax;
function makeAjax() {

    try{
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e) {
        try {
            ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert("Your browser is either OLD or BAD! UPDATE!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("btag").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with Firebug.  It's namespace issue.  Interestingly, XHTML 1.0 Strict does not even allow a form name attribute, so there's not even potential for this confusion.

Comment: Note that an input (or other form) element could still cause a similar issue, even in Strict.

Comment: i'm sorry i did not accept your answer, daniel got to me first.